# Alguna forma de que funcione un filtro HTML en Django con datos dinamicos

Tags: html, jquery, django

vi la solución de la pregunta "como hacer el motor de busqueda de mi aplicación en django"; sin embargo, he tratado de usar un filtro de html de esos que filtran una tabla en el navegador y van borrando datos hasta que dejan solo la data que se parece al criterio que se introdujo en la caja de texto que es para buscar. pero no me funciona el Jquery  con los datos dinamicos traídos a la tabla desde una base de datos. la pregunta hay alguna forma de resolver el filtrado en el navegador ya que todos los datos estan desplegados, o es ilogica la idea y solo se puede hacer desde las vistas.  algun truco??  bueno agradezco cualquier respuesta que me aclare la duda.   muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

si lo puedes hacer del html, lo puedes lograr con javascript o con jquery

aqui un ejemplo donde puede ver un poco de código

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table

saludos

Comment: gracias Derleguan,  si en html y javascript no hay problema, pero cuando los datos son dinamicos que vienen de una base de datos entonces ya el html no es suficiente y hay que usar un lenguaje de programacion con php, python, ruby, etc.  este filtro lo he usado con PHP,  pero con DJANgo me pierdo y todos los intentos que he usado no me funcionan, en PHP se puede ir filtrando en tiempo real; sin embargo lo que mas cercano he visto en django es enviando el filtro con un boton, pero yo quiero que se comporte igualito que en html y php, y no consigo una senda por ahí.   gracias!!!

Comment: max en django para ir filtrando es fácil. te explico realizas una consulta onda  consultados = modelo.objects.all()  con eso te traes todo lo del modelo ahora eso lo seteas en una variable y de esa variable puedes ir filtrando asi consultado.filter(campo1=dato,campo2=dato,etc) ahora para eso tienes que tener un modelo claro y conocido

Answer (score 0):

Al ser dinámicos no lo puedes hacer con filtros (templatetags) la mejor opción es utilizar AJAX, para hacer llamadas a una función o una vista de Python y luego renderizar desde la respuesta de AJAX el html